# npm-debug.log not generated on error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

According to the npm docs "On failure, all logs are written to npm-debug.log in the current working directory." however on build error I don't get a log file written. Current settings

$>npm config list

```
cwd = /home/me/mynodeapp
HOME = /home/me
```

$>npm config ls -l

```
loglevel = "warn"
```

webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
  loglevel: 'silly',
  entry: {
    app: './myapp/start.js'
  },
  output: {
    ...
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
{ "name" : "myapp",
  "main": "start.js",
   "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./output/ && NODE_ENV=production node node_modules/.bin/webpack",
  },
  ...
}
```

then on npm run build I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./myapp/start.js
Module build failed: TypeError: ....
```

But no npm-debug.log file was generated in/home/me/mynodeapp (directory from which I can npm install and npm run build, and the cwd according to npm config). NB I am the owner of the directory and subdirectories and have write permission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kinda strange why its not getting you an npm log. Maybe try something like this when you run your command: `npm run build 2>&1 > npm_error_log.txt`. This will output stderr and stdout to a file for easy reading.

Comment: that at least gave me an output file. Problem was with currupt node install I think, I reinstalled and works OK

Comment: @DonSmythe Interesting. From my experience node can be pretty finicky sometimes and yeah, a reinstallation usually solves the problem. Mostly node_modules being corrupted is where I run into problems though.